# How do I get all the keys that are stored in the Cassandra 2.0.1 column family with scala using hector?

Tags: scala, cassandra, hector, cassandra-cli, column-family

I have to enter some values with a key(suppose `key1="1_100"`), but before inserting the values i want to check that is key("`1_100`") is already inserted or not.I know it will replace the previous one, if exists. i only want to enter values if key is not exists.

### i am using cassandra cli.

```
    CREATE COLUMN FAMILY mytable
WITH comparator = UTF8Type
AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type
AND column_metadata = [
{column_name: id, validation_class: UTF8Type},
{column_name: name, validation_class: UTF8Type},
{column_name: tagLine, validation_class: UTF8Type},
{column_name: introduction, validation_class: UTF8Type},
{column_name: webAddress, validation_class: UTF8Type}
];
```

rowkeys are...

```
RowKey:1_100
RowKey:1_101
RowKey:2_100
RowKey:3_100
RowKey:1_105
RowKey:2_104
RowKey:3_101
```

and want to know now how to get these Rowkeys through hector in cassandra cli with scala

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cassandra 2.0 then you can do this using the normal `INSERT` CQL statement followed by `IF NOT EXISTS`:

> INSERT INTO your_table (key1) values ("1_100") IF NOT EXISTS

As shown here, this is best done with CQL and the native CQL driver; the functionality is exposed over Thrift as the `cas` method, but neither the cli nor Hector have been updated to support this and probably never will be.

If you are using Cassandra 1.2 or older, this is not possible.

Comment: i am using cassandra cli

Comment: @GovindSingh  without knowing what version are you using and the table definition is difficult to provide a complete answer

Comment: Edited the answer to clarify that you're SOL using the cli.

Answer (score 1):

```
val rangeSlice = HFactory.createRangeSlicesQuery(keyspace, se, se, se)
rangeSlice.setColumnFamily("myTable")
rangeSlice.setKeys(null, null)
rangeSlice.setRange(null, null, true, Int.MaxValue)
val bIterator = rangeSlice.execute().get.iterator()
while (bIterator.hasNext()) {
  val myRow = bIterator.next()
  val myKey = myRow.getKey()
  println(myKey+"<<<this is key")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val rangeSlice = HFactory.createRangeSlicesQuery(keyspace, se, se, se)
rangeSlice.setColumnFamily("myTable")
rangeSlice.setReturnKeysOnly();
val bIterator = rangeSlice.execute().get.iterator()
while (bIterator.hasNext()) {
val myKey =bIterator.next().getKey()
 println(myKey+"<<<this is key")
}
```